# take a screenshot (with root)

Tags: android, screenshot, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-screen

So I have this code to take a screenshot to any screen on rooted devices, but doesn't seems to work!
my device has the 2.3.7 android version, and I don't know if I can use `screencap` in this terms.
If I can use it, do I have to download any c or cpp file?

```
Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
os.flush();
os.close();
sh.waitFor()
```

still I added this check directory code to check if screenshot was taked:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/img.png");
            if(f.isDirectory() && f.isDirectory()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot taked", 0).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Screenshot not taked", 0).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

With root explorer, I went to `System/bin` directory, and the file `screencap` isn't there, so I assume that screencap isn't supported by this android version (2.3.7)